# High-level language decompiler on WIndows

Tags: assembly, c, disassemblers

So I have been using Binary ninja and I was wondering if there was any other tool except IDA or any binary ninja plugin that would transform assembly code into high level code, I already tried [binja-retdec](https://github.com/hugsy/binja-retdec) and [retdec-offline](https://github.com/ThisIsSecurity/retdec_offline). Both of them don't work giving me a thread run error or a file generation error, any idea?

Comment: For issues with software check the support options provided in the documentation or source code.

Comment: As a reverse engineer you have to be industrious. And this can mean getting your hands dirty by digging through the code that fails you (in this case it's even open source, so what's the big deal? ;)).

Answer (score 4):

[Ghidra](https://www.nsa.gov/resources/everyone/ghidra/) is a great tool that supports decompile for many CPU architectures.

Answer (score 1):

[Reko](https://github.com/uxmal/reko) supports a variety of processor architectures.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Relyze](https://www.relyze.com/overview.html), the standard version is free and contains a native code decompiler for x86/64/arm/arm64 PE and ELF binaries.

[image]